# docker-compose cannot connect to the asp.net core site

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am trying to run the docker-compose for ASP.NET Core application according to https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3 on Windows Server 2016.

Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Community.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: linuxchata/community-app:v1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:4000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Service has been created by running the following command

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml community
```

docker service ls command

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                         PORTS
t5jsy98xkl5p        community_web       replicated          1/1                 linuxchata/community-app:v1   *:80->4000/tcp
```

http://127.0.0.1:4000/, http://localhost:4000/ and http://servername:4000/ are not available via the browser. However, running individual container is working as expected (via docker run command).

Could you please advise what might be an issue here? More details are below.

docker version command

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:28 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:        Wed Mar 21 23:21:06 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

docker info command

```
Containers: 7
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 24
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: kdeu85ro38qhzffzo58ck9c2x
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: agtu0rm8l10rwkuoqlt6fdtzs
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.0.0.5
 Manager Addresses:
  10.0.0.5:2377
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2125.amd64fre.rs1_release.180301-2139)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 8GiB
Name: Server2016
ID: MPSV:4IF7:K6LN:FD2L:U4U4:OAW6:4JSQ:RDCK:JN3G:BZQF:24AW:5EII
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 16604
 System Time: 2018-05-16T19:56:26.9114443Z
 EventsListeners: 2
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker network inspect community_webnet command

```
[
    {
        "Name": "community_webnet",
        "Id": "n2rk9sh5ialmdg5x0s4k10q5y",
        "Created": "2018-05-16T19:15:39.8464593Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.1.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.1.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "c4fcafb9f810c95769c6456b7a3d0e0ac6b398672468b86e07d0d76981665ddd": {
                "Name": "community_web.1.4lijwfo1g0wi1kdxf87i01nx4",
                "EndpointID": "2272330e9dbebbd5eead54d3d476354c79d94dc2d363c8d44560acc4c5128627",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:48:8f:d9",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.15/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "community_webnet-sbox": {
                "Name": "community_webnet-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "9f6d2cd49c4aad73c7d82432d654cd202dd550956d6857378737a358eba7b8b1",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:48:8b:ac",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.1.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4102",
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "64b76ba8-f0de-4516-aaa8-952855cbd1da"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "community"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "d3045df8c95e",
                "IP": "10.0.0.5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to bind the dotnet command on Dockerfile to IP 0.0.0.0 ?  `e.g. dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:4000`

Comment: Yes, with this command, asp.net core application is up and running. Moreover, separate image linuxchata/community-app:v1 also can be run as container without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct docker compose file

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  web:
    image: linuxchata/community-app:v1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Command to run docker compose `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`